# How can I add, from another operating system, a script for execution on the next Windows boot?

Tags: windows, boot, script

> **Also known as**: adding a script on some Windows startup *without booting*
>   it

I have a **multiple operating systems** computer, one of them is Windows, and I would like to add some *.cmd* script to the **boot sequence of this Windows**, for example, this `StartTelnet.cmd`:

```
net start telnet
```

I prefer it to run with **administrator's privileges**, but any other user's could be better than nothing.

The main question is: I would like to make this change **from another operating system**, this is: **without booting** into that operating system that will be changed.

Is it possible? If yes, what file/s should I change or where should I put my startup script?

The  *changer O.S.* could be any Windows or Linux, I don't mind. The *changed O.S.* will be Windows 7, but answers for XP would we great too.

Answer (score 0):

To add a command/script to be executed you have just to edit the registry of Windows OS to be changed.

key => HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run and add value = path.

Commands/scripts requiring admin rights cannot be executed this way ([see UAC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-is-user-account-control#1TC=windows-7)).

a) Google for edit Windows registry under Linux (don't remember tool name).

b) In Windows you can edit another Windows OS registry by loading registry hive like "SYSTEM" or "SOFTWARE" from drive_letter:\Windows\System32\config. After edit unload hive.

Be careful when editing Windows registry ;)

Comment: The main flaw with this method is the need of user logon.

Comment: User logon to any system is a must as you want to edit. Any editor runs on some kind of OS ! Agree ? What do you want to do exactly - outline as 1. 2. 3. 4. - we will find the answer if possible ;)

Comment: in my original post (the question) I suggested an example with a simple `StartTelnet.cmd`. That could enough, since I accept that GUI requires user logon. The behavior is the same for `rc.local` in Linux: you can not start, say, **firefox**, but you can order some sort of `/etc/init.d/ssh start`.

Answer (score -1):

Lets Say that you Have

Windows 7 #1 -- Windows 7 #2

And you are booted to Windows 7 #1 with C:/ your Active Partition and D:/ your Second Operation System Partition.

You will have to add your file in this folder:

> D:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

And your program should start on the next Windows 7 #2 Boot.

Comment: Will the program run next time you ***boot*** machine #2, or only after somebody logs in to it?

Comment: This Folder is not assigned to a particular User. So it will start on Windows Startup.


Edit: Also Reffering to Microsoft's Site As states here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/run-program-automatically-windows-starts#1TC=windows-7
 Program will start on Windows next Startup

Comment: Is there an equivalent for Windows XP, @Devian?

Comment: D:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Comment: Didn't worked for you?